# Inserting rows to a table based on user input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried to generate the rows using javascript, but i'm learning jquery and I wish to use it to implement this functionality.

HTML

```
<form id="sizePicker">
    Grid Height:
    <input type="number" id="input_height" name="height" min="1" value="1">
    Grid Width:
    <input type="number" id="input_width" name="width" min="1" value="1">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<table id="pixel_canvas"></table>
```

JAVASCRIPT/JQUERY

```
function makeGrid() {
   var table = document.getElementById("pixel_canvas");
   //var table = $('#pixel_canvas');
   table.innerHTML = "";

   while($('#pixel_canvas tr').length > 0)
       table.deleteRow(0);
       var inputHeight = $('#input_height').val();
       var inputWidth = $('#input_width').val();
  for(var i = 0; i < inputHeight; i++){
       var row = table.insertRow(i);
       for(var j = 0; j < inputWidth; j++){
           var cell = row.insertCell(j);
       } 
   }
   return false;
}
sizePicker.submit(function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    makeGrid();
});
```

Here, the table DOM methods such as insertRow() and insertCell() is inactive if I implement the same methods using jquery.

```
var table = $('#pixel_canvas');
  var row = table.insertRow(i); // The browser responses not a function
```

Comment: In order to access the actual dom element returned by jquery, you will need to use: `var table = $('#pixel_canvas')[0];`.

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Thanks @Brian that helped a lot. But if you check my code you will see the line i wrote while($('#pixel_canvas tr').length > 0, i want to actually check the number of rows available. In Javascript I do while(table.row.length > 0), why is the row and length properties not working in jquery, i thought jquery is a javascript library

Comment: Ah, in that case you might want to do something like this: `$('#pixel_canvas tr').remove();`

Comment: Here is a jquery solution in case you're interested: https://jsbin.com/pixopupoqu/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

`insertRow` is Javascript DOM function. So, with JQuery you have to fetch the DOM element and not the jquery object. Use `$('#pixel_canvas').get(0)` to fetch the DOM element.

```js
function makeGrid() {
   var table = $('#pixel_canvas').get(0);
   table.innerHTML = "";

   while($('#pixel_canvas tr').length > 0)
       table.deleteRow(0);
       
    var inputHeight = $('#input_height').val();
    var inputWidth = $('#input_width').val();
    
    for(var i = 0; i < inputHeight; i++){
         var row = table.insertRow(i);
         for(var j = 0; j < inputWidth; j++){
             var cell = row.insertCell(j);
         } 
     }
   return false;
}

$('#sizePicker').submit(function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    makeGrid();
});
```

```css
table, th, td {
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="sizePicker">
    Grid Height:
    <input type="number" id="input_height" name="height" min="1" value="1">
    Grid Width:
    <input type="number" id="input_width" name="width" min="1" value="1">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<table id="pixel_canvas"></table>
```